# HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy

Tags: javascript

```
var fieldArray = [];
var fields = {{ json_encode(Config::get('planner.'.$viewType.'_view_jobs')) }};
for(var i in fields) {
    fieldArray.push([i, fields [i]]);
}
var outDiv = document.createElement('div');

for (var x = 0; x < fieldArray.length; x++) {
    container[x] = document.createElement('div');
    label[x] = document.createElement('div');
    label[x].className = "label-job control-label";
    $(label[x]).text(fieldArray[x][0]);
    value[x] = document.createElement('div');
    value[x].className = "label-value numeric";
    eval("$(value[x]).text(event." + fieldArray[x][1] + ");");
    container[x].appendChild(label[x]);
    container[x].appendChild(value[x]);
}
outDiv.appendChild(container);

element.attr("data-toggle", "popover");
element.attr("data-content", $(outDiv).text());
element.append("<br />");
```

Hi All, this is my code. I am trying to append multiple 'label', 'value' into 'container'. Then append multiple 'container' into 'OutDiv'. However I got this error.

```
fieldArray = [["Ttl Job", "ttl_job"], ["Ctr Job", "ctr_job"]];
```

label, value, container is the var that store my createElementDiv
I really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: What is `fieldArray`, `container`, `label`, and `value`. please update you question. And of course don't forget to format your code.

Comment: @mortezaT: I have edited my code and specifies the `fieldArray`, `container`, `label` and `value`.

Comment: Please add your error message and stack trace too.

Comment: I solved the problem. By moved outDiv.appendChild(container); into the for loop. Then change it to outDiv.appendChild(container[x]);